# How to connect VisualStudio 2017 to specific AOS AX2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have installed the *Visual Studio 2017*. In order to try to connect to my environment,
I used the the command property

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /AxConfig C:\MY_AXC_VAR.axc

[image]

But I have this error

> Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : AxConfig.

[image]

There is any way to connect the Visual Studio 2017 to specific Dynamics AX 2012 AOS/environment? Or I have to install another VS extension and update?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio 2017 is supported for AX 2012. The latest supported version seems to be Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Hi @FH-Inway thanks for your reply.
I checked everywhere..scientific literature ... version 2017 is not supported.
Thanks, I'll close the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many have advised me, Visual Studio 2017 is not supported for AX2012.

I listed below some info:

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/254146/why-ax2012-does-not-support-visual-studio-2017/890167

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/visual-studio-development-for-microsoft-dynamics-ax?redirectedfrom=MSDN

at Page 24:

https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/3/C/43CC518C-072D-409C-AC1D-020B7DA3A5FB/Microsoft%20Dynamics%20AX%202012%20System%20Requirements.pdf

Thanks all.